# Form works in IE fails in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, forms, firefox

This is a simple script to select a State then depending on the State chosen select a Region, then click to go to that Web Site

It works perfectly in IE.

the code is on http://goldcoast.info/Chat.php

I have tried a lot of things to try get this to work in Firefox, symptom is when you click on the button it will not go to the selected web site.

How would I get this working in Firefox?

```
<script language='JavaScript'>   
function setOptions(chosen) {
var selbox = document.myform.opttwo;
selbox.options.length = 0;
if (chosen == " ") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Please Select State',' ');
}
if (chosen == "NSW") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Blue Mountains','bluemountains.info');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Coffs Coast','coffscoast.info');
}
if (chosen == "QLD") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Cairns','cairns.info');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('The Gold Coast','goldcoast.info');
}
if (chosen == "VIC") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Geelong','geelong.info');
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Phillip Island','phillipisland.info');
}
}
</script>
<form name="myform"><div class="centre">
State<br>
<select name="optone" size="1"
onchange="setOptions(document.myform.optone.options[document.myform.optone.selectedIndex].value);">
<option value=" " selected="selected"> </option>
<option value="NSW">New South Wales</option>
<option value="QLD">Queensland</option>
<option value="VIC">Victoria</option>
</select><br>Region<br>
<select name="opttwo" size="1">
<option value=" " selected="selected">Please Select State</option>
</select><br />
<input class="red" type="button" name="go" value="Go There"
onclick="window.location.href('http://' + document.myform.opttwo.options[document.myform.opttwo.selectedIndex].value + '/index.php');return false">
</div></form>
```

Comment: You'll have to provide a few more details than "fails in Firefox".

Comment: When you click on the [Go There] button in Firefox it does nothing, in IE it goes to the web site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebug shows warnings, so many warnings, about what Brendan wrote. It also says `pfcClient is not defined` - try to fix that. And get rid of all these warnings from php script.

Comment: Thanks, I made a more simple test example                 
http://4ustralia.info/siteswitch

Comment: Ok, now in that Firebug I only see one error, window.location.href is not a function

Comment: I did it like this onclick="gotowebsite();"> then function gotowebsite()
{
var path = 'http://' + document.myform.opttwo.options[document.myform.opttwo.selectedIndex].value + '/index.php';
window.location.href = path;
return false;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="myform">

var selbox = document.myform.opttwo;
```

I don't think this will work in Firefox. Try using an ID:

```
<form id="myform">

var selbox = document.getElementById("myform").opttwo;
```

Comment: Thankyou, I tried that, however if I do that I cannot select a region in both IE and Firefox

Comment: ok I figured it out at last, using that firebug tool, wow that's cool, it's no wonder you guy's can figure all this stuff out :-) I just had to add it as a second function.